# Pbs Dependant Partner VIsa

Tags: united-kingdom

I would like to ask about the documents I submit regarding Proof of Relationship.If it's genuine. I submitted Marriage Certificate,Hotel and Wedding Reception Contract,Photo's and video Contract and our Wedding Photos and some screenshot from our Facebook post from the past few years. Is this okay to prove that our relationship is genuine.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK the Home Office does not publish set requirements for the kinds of documents that should be produced to substantiate that your relationship is “genuine and subsisting”. Factors that may put you at risk of refusal include:

- The relationship is relatively short
- You have only met a few times in person
- Your wedding was attended by very few or no guests
- You are married but you have been living in different countries for a long time

Particularly if any of the above apply to you, you might consider providing additional evidence such as:

- having your spouse write a letter confirming background details about the relationship such as when and how you met; when you decided to get married, and what plans you have made for your life together while in the UK;
- documentary evidence of time spent living together such as jointly-addressed mail, household bills;
- tickets showing visits to one another or travel together, and photos labelled with times and dates;
- evidence of shared responsibilities such as joint finances or financial support from one party to another.

Comment: It seems to me that a letter from the spouse would have little to no weight (speaking generally, of course), because the spouse could easily say whatever sounds good just for the purpose of the application.  Do you have personal experience or a reputable source that supports the idea that such a letter could be useful?

Comment: @phoog My solicitor told me to do this. Presumably they thought it was useful, obviously no way of knowing whether the ECO cared!

Comment: @MJeffryes thanks for mentioning that.  Can we presume that the application was successful?

Comment: @phoog Indeed. I suppose the thinking is that it can't hurt and can help tie together other parts of the evidence.

Comment: @MJeffryes Thanks, is it also the only piece of actual evidence from the UK-visa holding spouse (excluding the marriage certificate, I suppose) since it’s the dependent who applies rather than the spouse?

Comment: @Traveller Isn't the spouse's ID required? I don't know what the guidance is off the top of my head, since I just followed solicitor's instructions.